# 4-20 mA Sensor to Raspberry Pi: Inconsistent readings

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, 4-20ma

I have a 4-20 mA sensor that I want to read it with a Raspberry Pi. I use a [DFRobot Current to Voltage converter board](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1755.html) connected to an ADC (ADS 1115) that is connected to a Pi. So that way I can read the current from the sensor in the pi.

Along with this circuitry - I also have many other peripherals in my circuit board (Eg. Relays - 12VDC, Some other LP filter circuits, etc)

Now what is happening is that when I try to read the sensor from the Pi it reads accurately (4.9 mA) for some time, but as soon as the relay switches ON/OFF (They are connected to 12V electric ball valves) the value of the current jumps from 4.9 mA to 5.2 mA. I know that correct & accurate reading is 4.9 mA.

Now, as soon as I disconnect the sensor from the board and reconnect it again immediately the reading drops back to 4.9 mA and stays at that level until any relay activity.

1st Question: Why is this happening?
2nd Question: How can I fix it? Maybe a LP Filter or something?

I really appreciate everyone's time towards this and thankful for the community.

Best,
Kumar

Comment: If everything were linear, it would be possible to jump from 4.9 to 5.2 for a moment during switching but it would not be possible to hover there. So there is a non-linearity (and/or some kind of charge storage effect added to a non-linearity) involved in order for that to happen. I might look for a protection diode that goes on and then stays on, leaking current, for example. Or a latching effect. Or some rapidly charged (through diode), slowly discharged (through resistance) capacitance somewhere.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that information. I just did a test on the system that is somewhat relevant to linear vs non-linear. I left the Pi reading at the higher current level for extended period of time without having the relay switch ON/OFF to see for how long it sustains, and if it ever comes down or not. 

After leaving it for an hour the current value dropped from 5.25 mA to 5.18 mA, and after that as soon as I disconnected and reconnected the sensor the current dropped to 4.91 mA. Maybe this information helps you understand better on what is happening.

Comment: Have you connected a current meter in series with your current loop to verify that the Pi is reading accurately after the glitch? Perhaps the sensor outputs the wrong reading when the valves are switched. Have you measured the intermediate voltages? Perhaps the I to V converter or the Pi doesn't like the glitch.

Comment: You need to make some intermediate measurements to isolate the problem. Put a current meter in the high side of the 4~20mA loop and check that reading. If it does not change then measure the voltages at the inputs and output of the I-V converter. That will at least tie it down (more or less) to one module. Have you grounded the I-V converter low side input  to a system ground common with the ADC module and Pi?

Comment: Hello All, I haven't been able to solve this issue yet. 

I have been doing a lot of testing on the circuit and have discovered some things that may help us determine the issue. 
1. As I mentioned above that the valves are creating the jump, that is not the case. I isolated the circuitry from the valves and did the testing and it is still the same issue. The sensor reads a higher current and as soon as I disconnect and connect the sensor back again it drops to the correct value.

Comment: 2. I tested with my multimeter and the Pi is reading the correct values as read by the multimeter. So no issues from the ADC & Pi end.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I think you bring up a very important point. Can you please talk more about grounding the I-V convertor low side to the system ground? I have not done that in my circuit yet and feel like my value might be floating because of that.

Comment: Another update: I did try to connect the low-side of the 4-20 current loop with ground in hopes that it would solve the issue. But it ended up damaging my sensor, so I have reverted that change and luckily I had another sensor sitting that I am using now to do testing.